# Studying for the graduate entrance exam at CSULA

Tags: education

I'm an undergraduate student, but not a computer science major. I'm thinking of switching to CS after I graduate. I found a program that seems to allow students to take a test and gain entry into their school without having majored specifically in computer science first.

Here's the link: http://www.calstatela.edu/sites/default/files/groups/Department%20of%20Computer%20Science/sample_assessment_test.pdf

What online resources (YouTube videos, online courses, etc.) would enable someone without workplace or coding experience to fully address each of the prompts on this entrance exam?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing the work and the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you should be asking your professors.

Comment: That said, the test seems to cover learning objectives of specific courses. Take them, or self-learn the respective content.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll be sure to phrase questions with more precision in the future in order to emphasize the questions' universal aspects and to paint clearer pictures for potential responders. I think the CS professors at my current college would be a great start. Thanks for the insight about how the test relates to course-specific material.